# django-haystack: get_absolute_url for searchresult returning list object: ['/test/2018/05/06/something_testing/']

Tags: python, django, solr

Posting for the first time. Please forgive any mistakes I made.

I am trying to build a knowledge base site. I got it haystack working **django==2.0.3**.

I can see search results. However, in my search templates for **href tag** I can see list object for `get_absolute_url` as:

> ['/test/2018/05/06/something_testing/']

Because of this url redirection is not working properly as `'[]'` these brackets are coming in between.

views.py:

```
@login_required
def techpost_search(request):
    form = SearchForm()
    object_list= Techpost.published.all()
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = SearchForm(request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            query= request.GET.get('query')
            # results = Techpost.published.filter(Q(title__icontains=query) |           Q(body__icontains=query))
            results = SearchQuerySet().models(Techpost).filter(content=cd['query'])
            total_results = results.count()
            return render(request, 'rincon/search.html', {'form':form,  'results': results, 'total_results': total_results, 'cd': cd})
     return render(request, 'rincon/search.html', {'form':form,})
```

search_index.py:

```
class TechpostIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    publish = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='publish')
    title = indexes.CharField(model_attr='title')
    author = indexes.CharField(model_attr='author')
    url = indexes.CharField()

    def get_model(self):    
        return Techpost

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        return self.get_model().published.all()

    def prepare_url(self, obj):
        return (''.join(obj.get_absolute_url()))
```

search.html:

```
{% block content %}

{% if "query" in request.GET %}
<h4>techposts containing "{{ cd.query }}"</h4>
<h5>Found {{ total_results }} result{{ total_results|pluralize}}</h5>

{% for result in results %}

    {% with techpost=result %}
       <a href="{{ techpost.url}}">{{ techpost.title }} </a>
       <p class="date"> Published {{ techpost.publish }} by {{ techpost.author }}</p>
    {% endwith %}

{% empty %}
    <p>There are no results for your query.</p>
    <p><a href="{% url 'rincon:techpost_search' %}">Search again</a></p>
{% endfor %}

{% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

The URL:

```
# Current Full URL:
https://example.com/rincon/search/['/rincon/2018/05/06/mapi-auto-reply-configuration-oceanfax/']

# Desired URL:
https://example.com/rincon/2018/05/06/mapi-auto-reply-configuration-oceanfax/
```

requirements:

```
certifi==2018.4.16
chardet==3.0.4
defusedxml==0.5.0
Django==2.0.3
django-allauth==0.36.0
django-crispy-forms==1.7.2
django-haystack==2.8.1
django-taggit==0.22.2
idna==2.6
Markdown==2.6.11
oauthlib==2.0.7
psycopg2==2.7.4
pysolr==3.7.0
python3-openid==3.1.0
pytz==2018.4
requests==2.18.4
requests-oauthlib==0.8.0
urllib3==1.22
solr 6.6.3
```

Comment: OK, posting for the first time. Welcome! But it would help if you'd actually ask a question :) It seems something needs to be done, but where are you stuck trying it?

Comment: i am stuck at url redirection which is get_absolute_ url which is returning list object i.e ['/rincon/2018/05/06/mapi-auto-reply-configuration-oceanfax/']. I want this to be /rincon/2018/05/06/mapi-auto-reply-configuration-oceanfax/

Comment: Sure, that's clear but that's still not a question. It's a requirement. Are you asking "could you fix this for me?" or "what's wrong with my own attempt at fixing it?" (code follows)? The latter type of question has a far better chance of receiving answers. Also, please note that you can edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like you haven't implemented the Solr schema from Haystack. If you don't - and you're just running Solr in Schemaless mode - all fields are multivalued by default. And when these fields are returned, they are returned as a JSON array (i.e. ['foo', 'bar'], etc.).

You can [generate the schema.xml file](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/master/installing_search_engines.html) (and solrconfig.xml) for a single Solr server by using `build_solr_schema`:

```
./manage.py build_solr_schema --configure-directory=<CoreConfigDif> --reload-core
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked! had to update 'ADMIN_URL' in settings.py for solr and build_solr_schema with RELOAD_CORE worked.